# how to replace text in between brackets with html using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

this is the html with the text in between brackets:

```
<div class="someClass" style="width: 100%; ">Dealing flop: [Ks, 5c, 8h]</div>
```

this is what i want to end up with:

```
<div class="someClass" style="width: 100%; ">Dealing flop: [<span style='color: #000;>K♠</span>, <span style='color: #000;>5♣</span>, <span style='color: #f00;>8♥</span>]</div>
```

i tried this:

```
$('.someClass').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("km_done");
    var tt = $(this).html();
    if(tt.indexOf("[")!=-1){
        var cards = tt.slice(tt.indexOf("[")+1 ,tt.indexOf("]") ).split(", ");  
        $.each(cards,function(id,val){
            $(this).replaceWith(tt.replace(val,getColor(val)))  
        });
    }
});
getColor = function(str){
var col;
switch( str.charAt(1) ){
    case "h": col = "<span style='color: red; font-weight:bold;'>"+str.charAt(0)+"♥</span>";
    break;
    case "d": col = "<span style='color: red; font-weight:bold;'>"+str.charAt(0)+"♦</span>";
    break;
    case "s": col = "<span style='color: black; font-weight:bold;'>"+str.charAt(0)+"♠</span>";
    break;
    case "c": col = "<span style='color: black; font-weight:bold;'>"+str.charAt(0)+"♣</span>";
    break;
    default: col = "exception getColor > "+str;
}
return col;
```

}

but as you can guess, it doesn't work :(

what am i doing wrong??

Comment: thank you all for the answers!! since i could only choose one, i chose the one that had the pretty regex. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cC2bp/1/) is a possible readable solution without colors:

```
$(function() {
    var text = $("div").text();
    var replaced = text.replace(/\[(.*)\]/, function( $0, $1 ) {
        return $1.replace(/(.)([hdsc])/g, function( $0, $1, $2 ) {
            switch($2) {
                case "h":
                    return $1.concat("♥");
                case "d":
                    return $1.concat("♦");
                case "s":
                    return $1.concat("♠");
                case "c":
                    return $1.concat("♣");
                default:
                    return $1;
            }
        });
    });

    $("div").text(replaced);
});
```

And with color [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cC2bp/3/):

```
$(function() {
    var text = $("div").text();
    var replaced = text.replace(/\[(.*)\]/, function( $0, $1 ) {
        return $1.replace(/(.)([hdsc])/g, function( $0, $1, $2 ) {
            switch($2) {
                case "h":
                    return "<span style='color: red;'>".concat($1, "♥", "</span>");
                case "d":
                    return "<span style='color: red;'>".concat($1, "♦", "</span>");
                case "s":
                    return "<span style='color: black;'>".concat($1, "♠", "</span>");
                case "c":
                    return "<span style='color: black;'>".concat($1, "♣", "</span>");
                default:
                    return $1;
            }
        });
    });

    $("div").html(replaced);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct; the following piece isn't working the way you expect it to:

```
$.each(cards,function(id,val){
    $(this).replaceWith(tt.replace(val,getColor(val)))  
});
```

The problem is that `this` inside of that `each` call is just an object that you're turning into a jQuery object. `replaceWith` isn't actually replacing the html that that object came from.

You should probably build up an HTML string as you go and use `html` to set the contents at the end:

```
$('.someClass').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("km_done");
    var tt = $(this).html();
    if (tt.indexOf("[") != -1) {
        var cards = tt.slice(tt.indexOf("[") + 1, tt.indexOf("]")).split(", ");
        var result = '';

        $.each(cards, function(id, val) {
            tt = (tt.replace(val, getColor(val)));
        });

        $(this).html(tt);
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zWbkj/

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you are inside the .each loop, $(this) is no longer the $('.someClass'). Set a variable to the jQuery object earlier in scope, and reference that:

http://pastie.org/2095747

Keep in mind though, the code still loops through and re-replaces it each time. Youll need to adjust it to get the content again each time in the loop from the element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/sharat87/v5Lqm/

The problem with your code is that in the `.each` call, I don't think the `this` refers neither to a DOM element, nor to a selector, not a valid one at least. So, what you are effectively doing is this

```
$('Ks').replaceWith...
```

Now, jQuery can't find any elements with the `Ks` tag, as they don't exist and so nothing happens. jQuery doesn't complain when you operate on 0 elements.

Study the code in the jsfiddle example I provided above, let me know if you have any more doubts :)